# How to implement with AutoBean a list of different base types like String, Integer, etc.?

Tags: java, gwt, json-rpc, autobean

I want to create a request for JSON-RPC with three parameters - String, Integer and my own object. Request should look like this:

```
{"method":"MyMethod", "params":["text", 123, {"name": "any text", "num": 15}], "id":1}
```

Ideally, I would like to create an AutoBean like this (but it does not work):

```
interface JsonRpcRequest {  

    String getJsonrpc();
    void setJsonrpc(String value);

    String getMethod();
    void setMethod(String value);

    List<Object> getParams(); // ERROR: Type Object may not be used
    void setParams(List<Object> params); // ERROR: Type Object may not be used

} 

interface JsonRpcRequestFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {

    AutoBean<JsonRpcRequest> jsonRpcRequest();

}
```

The problem is that the AutoBean framework does not allows the use of `List<Object>` inside interface.

Is there another way to create a list/array of elements of different based and non-based types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you simply can't. AutoBean requires everything to be *statically typed*: no polymorphism, and no mixed-typed lists of maps.

You might be interested by RequestFactory's built-in support for JSON-RPC though.

Answer (score 0):

Why do your params all need to be passed back in a list? Surely you're not going to do the same thing with a `String`, an `Integer`, and another `Object`! Just send them all back separately.

Further, you're not sending a custom `Object` over the JSON, you're sending the `objid` of that object... so just send the `Integer id` and let the server handle it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need a versatile and simple system. For example, I can sent to the server a sessionId and complex filter, which includes several field names and number of conditions. In addition, the server-side can be implemented not by me. I need a way to call a procedure with any number of parameters of any type.